# Finding implicit derivative $\frac{∂z}{∂x}$ in multivariable equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am pretty new to multivariable calculus, I know how to find $f_x$, $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$ etc. but that's about all.

I want to solve this question:

> Find the value of $\frac{∂z}{∂x}$ at the point (1, 1, 1) if the equation
>   $2xy + z^3x − yz = 2$
>   defines $z$ as a function of the two independent variables $x$ and $y$.

Edit:

Thanks to all the comments, I went ahead and tried to answer the question.
$$2xy + z^3x − yz = 2$$

$$2y+z^3+3z^2x\frac{∂z}{∂x}-y\frac{∂z}{∂x}=0$$

$$\frac{∂z}{∂x}(3z^2x-y)=-2y-z^3$$

$$\frac{∂z}{∂x}=\frac{-2y-z^3}{3z^2x-y}$$

at $(1, 1, 1)$:

$$\frac{∂z}{∂x}=\frac{-2(1)-(1)^3}{3(1)^2(1)-(1)}=-\frac{3}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: This is called _implicit differentiation_ because the function $z(x,y)$ is "implicitly" defined (it's defined by an equation other than the usual, "explicit" way $z(x,y)=\cdots$).

Comment: You probably want to use implicit differentiation.  Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, treating $y$ as independent of $x$, but $z$ depending on $x$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang  So when I differentiate 'z' I will have to put dz/dx after it like in a normal implicit differentiation question?

Comment: Well yeah, that's what it means to "treat $z$ as dependent on $x$"

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thanks, could you see if my answer is correct please

Comment: Yep, looks good.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang okay thank you!